# Importing Directx 12 texture to cuda surface: columns OK, rows screwed

Tags: cuda, directx-12

I'm trying to write a D3D12 texture from cuda. For this I map the D3D texture to a mipmap then a cudaArray. I can see the result expected modulo many columns are missing. What am I missing ?

Full sources: https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update

[image: unexpected result]

D2D12 part:

```
TextureChannels = 4;
TextureWidth = m_width;
TextureHeight = m_height;
const auto textureSurface = TextureWidth * TextureHeight;
const auto texturePixels = textureSurface * TextureChannels;
const auto textureSizeBytes = sizeof(float)* texturePixels;

D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC d3dTexDesc{};
d3dTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
d3dTexDesc.Format = TextureChannels == 4 ? DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT : DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
d3dTexDesc.Width = TextureWidth;
d3dTexDesc.Height = TextureHeight;
d3dTexDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
d3dTexDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
d3dTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
d3dTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
d3dTexDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;

ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(&CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT), D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_SHARED,
    &d3dTexDesc, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&TextureArray)));
NAME_D3D12_OBJECT(TextureArray);
```

Import/mapping part:

```
HANDLE sharedHandle{};
WindowsSecurityAttributes secAttr{};
LPCWSTR name{};
ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateSharedHandle(TextureArray.Get(), &secAttr, GENERIC_ALL, name, &sharedHandle));
const auto allocInfo = m_device->GetResourceAllocationInfo(m_nodeMask, 1, &d3dTexDesc);

cudaExternalMemoryHandleDesc cuExtmemHandleDesc{};
cuExtmemHandleDesc.type = cudaExternalMemoryHandleTypeD3D12Resource;
cuExtmemHandleDesc.handle.win32.handle = sharedHandle;
cuExtmemHandleDesc.size = allocInfo.SizeInBytes;
cuExtmemHandleDesc.flags = cudaExternalMemoryDedicated;
CheckCudaErrors(cudaImportExternalMemory(&m_externalMemory, &cuExtmemHandleDesc));

cudaExternalMemoryMipmappedArrayDesc cuExtmemMipDesc{};
cuExtmemMipDesc.extent = make_cudaExtent(TextureWidth, TextureHeight, 0);
cuExtmemMipDesc.formatDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float4>();
cuExtmemMipDesc.numLevels = 1;
CheckCudaErrors(cudaExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray(&cuMipArray, m_externalMemory, &cuExtmemMipDesc));
CheckCudaErrors(cudaGetMipmappedArrayLevel(&cuArray, cuMipArray, 0));

cudaResourceDesc cuResDesc{};
cuResDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
cuResDesc.res.array.array = cuArray;
checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&cuSurface, &cuResDesc));
```

Cuda part:

```
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return a % b != 0 ? a / b + 1 : a / b; }

__global__ void UpdateSurface(cudaSurfaceObject_t surf, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, float time)
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (y >= height | x >= width) return;

    auto xVar = (float)x / (float)width;
    auto yVar = (float)y / (float)height;
    auto cost = __cosf(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f;
    auto costx = __cosf(time) * 0.5f + xVar;
    auto costy = __cosf(time) * 0.5f + yVar;
    auto costxx = (__cosf(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f) * width;
    auto costyy = (__cosf(time) * 0.5f + 0.5f) * height;
    auto costxMany = __cosf(y * time) * 0.5f + yVar;
    auto costyMany = __cosf((float)x/100 * time) * 0.5f + xVar;
    auto margin = 1;

    float4 pixel{};
    if (y == 0)
        pixel = make_float4(costyMany * 0.3, costyMany * 1, costyMany * 0.4, 1);
    else if (y == height - 1)
        pixel = make_float4(costyMany * 0.6, costyMany * 0.7, costyMany * 1, 1);
    else if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (x > width / 2)
            pixel = make_float4(0.1, 0.5, costx * 1, 1);
        else
            pixel = make_float4(costx * 1, 0.1, 0.2, 1);
    }
    else if (x > width - margin - 1 | x <= margin)
        pixel = make_float4(costxMany, costxMany * 0.9, costxMany * 0.6, 1);
    else
        pixel = make_float4(costx * 0.3, costx * 0.4, costx * 0.6, 1);
    surf2Dwrite(pixel, surf, x, y);
}

void RunKernel(size_t textureW, size_t textureH, cudaSurfaceObject_t surfaceObject, cudaStream_t streamToRun, float animTime)
{
    auto unit = 16;
    dim3 threads(unit, unit);
    dim3 grid(iDivUp(textureW, unit), iDivUp(textureH, unit));
    UpdateSurface <<<grid, threads, 0, streamToRun >>> (surfaceObject, textureW, textureH, animTime);
    getLastCudaError("UpdateSurface execution failed.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end it was the cuda part that was not correct:
`surf2Dwrite`'s `x` must be multiplied by 16.

```
surf2Dwrite(pixel, surf, x * 16, y);
```

The final demo can be found at https://github.com/mprevot/CudaD3D12Update